# Android Development - Parsing JSON

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get the values from my mySql database and display them in a listView. However when I click the button to display them I get the following error message : org.json.JSONException: No value for establishments.

I know that the TAG_RESULTS is empty but I don't know what I'm supposed to put in to it.

Here is my code

```
public class SecondPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String myJSON;

    //There is no value for this TAG_RESULTS ON LINE 116
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="establishments";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PICTURE = "picture";

    JSONArray establishments_JSON = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> establishmentsList;
    //JSONArray establishments = null;
    //Array establishments = null;

    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.current_location_listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        establishmentsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }

    public void getData(){
        //changed the middle parameter to a string from a void
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                Log.d("GETTING JSON DATA", "HERE....");

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.102.11.109/findandeat_xampp_data/get_all_establishments.php");
                //String loginDetails = ServerConnection.RUSH_SERVER_ADDRESS + "login.php?userName=" + userNameInput + "&password=" + passwordInput;


                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                Log.d("STARTING INPUT STREAM", "HERE....");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                    Log.d("CATCH ANY ERRORS", "HERE....");

                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                Log.d("myjson",myJSON);

                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    protected void showList(){
        try {
            Log.d("myjson",myJSON);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            establishments_JSON = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<establishments_JSON.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = establishments_JSON.getJSONObject(i);
                String pizzeriaName = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String pizzeriaPicture = c.getString(TAG_PICTURE);

                String chineseName = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String chinesePicture = c.getString(TAG_PICTURE);

                String cafeName = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String cafePicture = c.getString(TAG_PICTURE);

                String indianName = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String indianPicture = c.getString(TAG_PICTURE);

                String ChipShopName = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String ChipShopPicture = c.getString(TAG_PICTURE);

                //Error im getting is that there is no value for the result
                //with the JSON

                HashMap<String,String> establishment_items = new HashMap<String,String>();

                establishment_items.put(TAG_NAME,pizzeriaName);
                establishment_items.put(TAG_PICTURE,pizzeriaPicture);

                establishment_items.put(TAG_NAME,chineseName);
                establishment_items.put(TAG_PICTURE,chinesePicture);

                establishment_items.put(TAG_NAME,cafeName);
                establishment_items.put(TAG_PICTURE,cafePicture);

                establishment_items.put(TAG_NAME,indianName);
                establishment_items.put(TAG_PICTURE,indianPicture);

                establishment_items.put(TAG_NAME,ChipShopName);
                establishment_items.put(TAG_PICTURE,ChipShopPicture);

                establishmentsList.add(establishment_items);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    SecondPage.this, establishmentsList, R.layout.activity_current_location_items,
                    new String[]{TAG_NAME,TAG_PICTURE},
                    new int[]{R.id.establishment_name, R.id.establishment_picture}
            );

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

XML[database column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xRTK.png)

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

[column name in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xRTK.png)
The other types of restuarants have the same naming system applied

Answer (score 0):

It will generate this error because there is the parameter you want. So you can validate:

```
//if exists
if(jsonObj.has(TAG_RESULTS)){

}
```

The same should do to verify certain parameters exist or not in the JSON object, so you save trouble with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

use `.has(String)` and `isNull(String)`

> **.has(String)** checks if the JSONObject contains a specific key
>
> **.isNull(String)** checks if the value associated with the key is null or if there is no value

So , your code will be

```
if (jsonObj.has(TAG_RESULTS) && !jsonObj.isNull(TAG_RESULTS)) {
    establishments_JSON = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
 }
```

I hope to be helpful for you .

Comment: Hi Abbbes Yassine, I tried your suggested code and I've still got the same message of no value. Im new to php and I think the problem might be in my php file which contains the following

Comment: `jsonObj.has(TAG_RESULTS)` return true ?